# javascript: target div in <a href ...>

Tags: javascript, html, target

I have 2 htm files: a.htm and b.htm. In b.htm I have 2 divs, in one is a link to a.htm which I would like to open in second div but it opens as new page in new tab. I'm not good in javascript but I looked many examples so I believe I'm very close to solution but obviously have some error somewhere. Please help!

So, in a.htm I have this:

```
<html>
    <body>
        TEST
    </body>
</html>
```

In b.htm I have this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            function url2div(url,target){
                document.getElementById(target).innerHTML = '<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%;" frameborder="0" src="' + url + '" />';
            }   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="menu" style="background-color:#FFD700;height:100px;width:100px;float:left;">
            <a href="a.htm" onclick="url2div(this.href,'content')">Click</a>
        </div>

        <div id="content" style="background-color:#EEEEEE;height:100px;width:400px;float:left;">
            Original content
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to make it `<a href="#" onclick="url2div('a.htm','content')">` instead, that will be more reliable. Or store `a.htm` in any property *except* the `href` ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sdwM9/))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store your link inside the function instead of the `href` attribute:

```
<a href="#" onclick="url2div('http://www.bing.com', this)">Click</a>
```

Change JS to this:

```
function url2div(url, element) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    iframe.setAttribute('src', url);
    element.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #1](http://jsfiddle.net/LRcmg/8/)**

if you want to open the link in the same `iframe`, store the link in any other property other than `href`. Then, use your current function and it should work fine!

```
<a href="#" id="a.htm" onclick="url2div(this.id,'content')">Click</a>
```

**[JSFiddle Demo #2](http://jsfiddle.net/haU2B/1/)**

Comment: Why did you get rid of the second argument to the function? What if they want to use this sort of technique in multiple separate divs?

Comment: Good point.. Updated the answer :) thank you @RevanProdigalKnight

Answer (score 0):

I think this isn't as complicated as you're making it. Also, the previous answer isn't quite doing what the OP is asking...so here's my stab at it:

First, I assume html5, so you don't need the "javascript" as part of your script tags. Secondly, I don't think you need to pass around all those variables. Your anchor tag should reference

```
 <a href=b.htm#content onclick="url2div();"<\a>
```

and your javascript should be

```
  otherPageText = "<iframe src=\"HtmlPage2.html\" width=\"200\" height=\"200\"></iframe>";
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = otherPageText;
```

After that, if you need variables, carefully try to pass them in one at a time.

Part of the original problem is that you're passing "this" which references the new page, not the old one, but by the time that happens you're on the new page and not bringing over the one you want back to the first page. Part of why I stayed away from it.

PS Sorry for the bad formatting. This is all very new to me...